# AVD manager not able to load installed system image

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

i installed android emulator's system image (API level 29) .i was able to download it and install it 
but even after successful installation it still shows me the "download" option.
it happened twice. im running on latest android studio v3.5.1 and avd v30.0.5 .
i have attached sdk screenshots ...

[image: sdk tool's screenshot]

[image: sdk platform's screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You installed the android 10 platform sdk. NOT System-Image.
In android studio: Tools --> AVD Manager --> Create Virtual Device button.
Select a hardware there and click next.
Now download one of the recommended system images. (Q is preferred)
Let it download... (It's size is about 1.5GB)
After you downloaded the system image, You can select it.

Comment: I kown that process i did it aswell it downloads system image unzips n installs it but again wen i try to lauch it show that same download button (which is already downloaded)